# How can I get iTerm out of fullscreen mode?

Tags: iterm

I must have hit some keystrokes which got me stuck in full screen mode and there are no resize icons when you hover mouse at top of screen even though the task bar shows up.  How do I get out of full screen without restarting iTerm?

Comment: It really is truly annoying as there's no UI elements to bring your out of full screen. Good question!

Comment: Ya know. I take back that comment, I actually use the Command enter all day long now.

Comment: Related, there's no menu option to disable CMD+ENTER, but you can add a new key binding to ignore it: https://superuser.com/questions/600573/disable-cmdenter-on-iterm-2

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This was probably how I got stuck there in the first place.  You can toggle full screen mode with the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Allan thanks for the edit, how do I add those doodads?

Comment: There's a [limited subset of HTML tags allowed on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)  In this case, you can encode your key within the <kbd></kbd> tag.  As for the "places mark" (the clover) and the Enter key symbol, press `Control-Command-Space` to bring up the "characters selector", search for them and insert as needed.  I suggest adding the ones you use most to your favorites.

Comment: alternatively, set the whole string as a replacement in keyboard/text. I use simply `ksomething`, so kcmd generates `<kbd> Cmd ⌘ </kbd>` etc

Comment: Sweet nectar! For some reason the little green button is not showing up

Comment: @dustbuster which green button?

Comment: Ya know. When you full screen and app on MacOs it gives you a red (close) yellow (minimize) and green (fullscreen toggle) buttons on the top left corner, those don’t seem to show up any more for iterm after it’s been fullscreened